# What are the SQL Server 2012 versions of FIRST() and LAST()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a table with a `value` column.  I want to calculate the last row minus the first row, as shown here:

```
 id      value
  1       10
  2       45
  3       65
  4       95
  .       .
  .       .
  .       .
 500     200
```

I want to obtain `200 - 10 = 190`

I've tried to use the below command in SQL Server 2012, however `LAST` and `FIRST` don't work.

```
SELECT LAST(Value) - FIRST(Value) FROM Counter;
```

What is the syntax for this command in SQL Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were close - `FIRST` and `LAST` are from Access; in SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2012) they are `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()`.

So, if you are 2012 or better (or Azure SQL Database), here's one way to get your answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #fl
(
  IdentityColumn INT IDENTITY, 
  Value INT
);

INSERT #fl(Value) SELECT 10;
INSERT #fl(Value) SELECT 45;
INSERT #fl(Value) SELECT 65;
INSERT #fl(Value) SELECT 95;
INSERT #fl(Value) SELECT 200;

SELECT TOP (1) LAST_VALUE(Value) OVER (ORDER BY IdentityColumn)
            - FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER (ORDER BY IdentityColumn)
  FROM #fl
  ORDER BY IdentityColumn DESC;

GO
DROP TABLE #fl;
```

Answer (score 10):

One more way (that works in older versions as well):

```
SELECT 
    result = (SELECT TOP (1) value FROM counter ORDER BY id DESC)
             - (SELECT TOP (1) value FROM counter ORDER BY id ASC) ;
```

Answer (score -3):

Why don't use the MAX and Min Function (Optional if you have Criteria use Where)

Eg. Select (Max(NumFieldName) - Min(NumFieldName)) AS Output FROM TableName

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `Value` column is always increasing. The identity column is, however.